# how do I read a text file lines and extract values into an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that contains information like this:

```
[406.7758007117438, 406.7758007117438, 406.7758007117438, 406.7758007117438, 406.7758007117438, 406.7758007117438],0,160p30
[450.3589222165735, 450.3589222165735, 450.3589222165735, 450.3589222165735, 450.3589222165735, 450.3589222165735],0,160p30
[496.23589222165737, 496.23589222165737, 496.23589222165737, 496.23589222165737, 496.23589222165737, 496.23589222165737],0,160p30
[545.9359430604982, 545.9359430604982, 545.9359430604982, 545.9359430604982, 545.9359430604982, 545.9359430604982],0,160p30
[587.2252160650737, 587.2252160650737, 587.2252160650737, 587.2252160650737, 587.2252160650737, 587.2252160650737],0,160p30
[630.8083375699034, 630.8083375699034, 630.8083375699034, 630.8083375699034, 630.8083375699034, 630.8083375699034],0,160p30
[292.08337569903404, 292.08337569903404, 292.08337569903404, 292.08337569903404, 292.08337569903404, 292.08337569903404],1,160p30
[344.07727503812913, 344.07727503812913, 344.07727503812913, 344.07727503812913, 344.07727503812913, 344.07727503812913],1,160p30
[391.4834773767158, 391.4834773767158, 391.4834773767158, 391.4834773767158, 391.4834773767158, 391.4834773767158],1,160p30
[448.06507371631926, 448.06507371631926, 448.06507371631926, 448.06507371631926, 448.06507371631926, 448.06507371631926],1,160p30
[501.5882053889171, 501.5882053889171, 501.5882053889171, 501.5882053889171, 501.5882053889171, 501.5882053889171],1,160p30
[552.8174885612608, 552.8174885612608, 552.8174885612608, 552.8174885612608, 552.8174885612608, 552.8174885612608],1,160p30
```

I want to read all lines that have the same values after `],` for example `0` and put the first column of these lines into one row an array similar to this:

```
[406.7758007117438,450.3589222165735,496.23589222165737,545.9359430604982,587.2252160650737,630.8083375699034]
```

finally, I will have an array in output with 6 columns each column contains the first columns of lines with similar values after `],`. the next rows are related to the next line with similar values after '],'
I used this code:

```
with open(fnames_psnr_tmp[j]) as f:
               lines = f.read().splitlines()
          tmp160 = [literal_eval(i.rsplit(',',1)[0]) for i in lines if ',0,' in I]
```

but I do not know what is the value of this number after `,]`in each file. In some files this value is `12` in some files it is `5`. how can I find this value for the last line in the file?I have the last line values in `lines` like this:

```
[519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992],12,160p30
```

how do I extract `12`in the above string? this shows the number of different line value that I have.
the output of the above code is a tuple. how can I read the first column of each tuple into an array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I extract a specific value from a string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74705579/how-do-i-extract-a-specific-value-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

If all your rows have the same lengths you can just eliminate the brackets with `replace(']','')` and `replace('[','')` then each row is easily split using `split(',')`. To accumulate the values for each "id" (trailing number) you can use a dict of lists with the id as keys:

```
data = dict()
for line in lines:
    line.replace(']','')
    line_data = line.split(',')
    # First 6 entries
    columns = line_data[0:6]
    trailing_number = line_data[6]
    if trailing_number in data:
        data[trailing_number].append(float(columns[0])) # append the value to the matching list
    else:
        data[trailing_number] = [float(columns[0]),] # Initialize a list for this id in the dict
```

You could use `int` or `float` to convert the strings to numbers if needed.