# how do I extract a specific value from a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a string with this structure:

```
[519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992],12,160p30
```

I need to find the value after `],` that here is `12`. I need this value to use in a `for` loop. how can I do this?

Comment: `mystring.split(',')[-2]`

Comment: In a for loop? Are there multiple strings that you need to loop through and extract the value after ]? Please post more of the data if so.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Does this assume his string is always the same length after the ]?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson why answering in comment ?

Comment: @CaptainCaveman: yes, but other `split` methods could work: `mystring.split(']').split(',')[1]`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson yes, and the question lacks enough information to know for sure.

Comment: You find the value the same way, regardless of where you need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is at the right end of your string, you can use `rsplit` instead of `split`

```py
s = "[519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992],12,160p30"
val = s.rsplit(",", 2)[1]  # val get value "12" from s
```

`rsplit` will split your string from the right starting at the separator `","` a maximum of 2 times. As you want the second to last value of your string, use indexing to get the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have same structure of data you can use regexp to extract part of strings you need to use. In described case it can be done like this:

```
import re


test_string = '[519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992, '\
                '519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992],'\
                '12,160p30'

pattern = r'(^\[.+\]),([0-9]+),(.+$)'

result = re.search(pattern, test_string)

print(result.group(1))
# [519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992, 519.1743772241992]

print(result.group(2))
# 12

print(result.group(3))
# 160p30
```